# css, float and margin

Tags: html, css

If I have for example html like this:

```
<div id="left">
  items
<div>
<div id="right">
  items
</div>
```

and css like this:

```
#left
{
  float: right;
}
#right
{
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

the margin of right block calculating from the left side of screen and not from right border of left div. How I can margin directly from right side of left block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to float both ***left***.

HTML

```
<div id="left">
  <!-- Left Content -->
</div>​

<div id="right">
  <!-- Right Content -->
</div>

<div class="clear"></div> <!-- Clear the floats -->
```

CSS

```
#left
{
  float: left;
}

#right
{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.clear
{
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flip around your divs and apply `float: right` to both. [Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/kBE4K/)

```
<div id="right">
  right
</div>
<div id="left">
  left
</div>​

#left
{
  float: right;
}
#right
{
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}​
```